# Java using eclipse

Tags: java, string

i just wrote a simple palindrome program in java using eclipse. I got this error

```
 for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++)
    {
        if(inputString[i]==inputString[(len-i-1)] //error here "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String"
        {
            palindrome = true;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {                    
            break;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

`String`s in Java aren't character arrays, they're [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)s. Try using `inputString.charAt(i)`.

Comment: and close the pharanthesis.

Comment: Another option is you convert it to a char array before comparison using s.toCharArray();

Comment: @AurA True, but operations on the actual object are the preferred OO idiom, and it seems that the OP is new to Java from C.

Comment: @chrylis in c# we can get an output like  "**the factorial of 2 is 2** " by writing a piece of code  
Console.WriteLine("the factorial of {0} is {1}",FactNum,fact);
   

how can we achieve the same in java

Comment: @Vivekh That's a completely different question; please post it as a new one.

Answer (score 3):

In Java there is a String class; it can't be treated like an array. As chrylis said, either use the charAt() method, or use the toCharArray() method to convert it into a char array.

It also looks like you have a bug with detecting if there is a palindrome. If the first and last character match, palindrome gets set to true. However, if the next two characters don't match, then it goes to the else branch of the conditional, where it will just exit the for loop. However, palindrome is still set to true. You could even just set palindrome to true before the for loop, and then it will only get set to false if the string is not a palindrome.

For the comparison you would want:

```
palindrome = true;
for(int i=0; i<len-1; i++)
{
    if(inputString.charAt(i)==inputString.charAt(len-i-1))
    {
        i++;
    }
    else
    {   
        palindrome = false;                 
        break;
    }
}
```